# Obtaining a copy of Shabbos Test By Harav Zalman Nechemia Goldberg

Tags: semicha

Due to the Coronavirus situation in Israel, does someone have a copy of the Shabbos Bechina (test) they can upload here? Clean copy if possible.

I’ve tried google to see if someone has uploaded.

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify why this is specifically due to the coronavirus? Because you can't do the test in person? Is he even accepting online tests?

Comment: As I live outside of Israel, people I’ve asked prefer not to go and get a copy due to the coronavirus and possibly C”V spread the disease. Once the coronavirus has ended at least I could send it then. But to work on it now whilst i have the time.